# what is a convenient way to create a series expression

Tags: html, css

It's there any convenient way to work out a series expression, like Emoji smile face, or something like that and allow users append to their post. My solution is to find those images one by one, and ground them to a specific file, and refer them seperately.
for expamle

```
<img src="expression/Emoji1.png" height="20" width="20" >
```

and grounp them to a container which holds this series small expression, and after the user click a specific expression, I can transfer the specific image to the corespondent tag which adds to the post text , like "I want to hang out today [laugh]", and the [laugh] refers to Emoji1.png

Comment: what do you mean by a series?

Comment: @stackErr, a set of small picture expression

Comment: These kind of things are done with Javascript and PHP. For example, with Javascript you instruct the code of the emoticon to be appended to the text when clicking on the corresponding picture, and before displaying the post use PHP to replace in the text submitted every code for the HTML code that represents each icon.

Comment: Here's something that will get you started - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/pLhVU/

Comment: @TimSPQR, this works properly when you have text within a div instead of a input element, then it's better to append some correspondent text like [expression1], then display accordingly and replace the tag [expression1] using the correspondent image